# Длинное нажатие на кнопки громкости

Tags: android

Делаю что то вроде мп3 плеера. Нужно, при заблокированой клавиатуре отследить длинное нажатие на кнопки громкости, сто бы переключать музыку. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Придется самому отлавливать время нажатия кнопки громкости через миллисекунды!

Алгоритм отслеживания:

Кнопка нажата впервые!

(1) установили флаг первого нажатия
(2) получили время.

Кнопка нажата более (к примеру) 2000 мс, действуйте!

Кнопку отпустили раньше 2000 мс:
(1) сбрасывайте флаг первого нажатия.

Используйте:
    onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {}